# MQ Connection - 2009 Connection broken error on active channel

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms, mq

I'm upgrading our application to MQ7 (7.5.0.5) and I'm seeing some odd behavior in a small test application that I have written.

My application uses Springs CachingConnectionFactory and is configured to use only one thread.

I can see that by debugging through the code 2 tcp connections are created, one for the initial connection and one for the JMS session. Every 60 seconds, the 2 tcp connections that are used by my message sink are broken and replaced with 2 new connections.

The following error is present in the error logs on the queue manager.

```
05/16/2016 09:38:26 AM - Process(1609.14) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                Host(xxxxxxxxx) Installation(Installation1)
                VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(xxxxx)

AMQ9271: Channel 'XX.XXXX.X' timed out.

EXPLANATION:
A timeout occurred while waiting to receive from the other end of channel
'XX.XXX.X'. The address of the remote end of the connection was     '57.4.4.145'.
ACTION:
The return code from the (recv) [TIMEOUT] 60 seconds call was 0 (X'0').     
Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
```

I have the following settings on my channel: DISCINT(60), SHARECNV(1), the exceptions are linked to the DISCINT time, changing that changes the frequency of the exceptions, also the 
exceptions disappear with a SHARECNV value >1

Can anyone tell my why the connections are broken even when the channel is active and messages are being sent and received?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like APAR IV62728 which describes the symptoms you're seeing:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IV62728

Fixed in 7.5.0.6. Try upgrading to that level and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that does indeed sound like my issue, but unfortunately after updating to 7.5.0.6 the issue is still happening.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. Recommend opening a PMR with IBM support to have them look into the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input Tim, I managed to keep the connection open by adjusting the HBINT value.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this issue. When using the CachingConnectionFactory with an underlying IBM connection factory, an initial connection is created in a stopped state. That connection in then used to create JMSSessions.

The issue was that the initial common connection was timing out.

I managed to keep the connection active by adjusting the HBINT value to 5. It appears that a number of heatbeats are required to keep the connection open and my initial value of 20 was too high.

Comment: Aggressive firewall, NAT, or similar?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not to familiar with that stuff. I'll be trying it out in our QA and prod sites in the next month or so, I'll see if I get similar results, and see if the mq or network guys spot anything.